# Where can you find all of the legendary materials?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are a bunch of new [legendary materials](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/crafting-material/) in Diablo 3, used to craft specific items. I need, for example, Element of Celerity, Quaking Vial, or Skelon's Dice to make some of the recipes I've found, but I have no idea where to find them.

Where can you find each of the new legendary crafting materials?

Comment: @Rapida Searched the site for "Element of Celerity", got no results. That question has terrible answers, and the tone of your question is more just about the Reaper's Wraps than everything (despite your title).

Comment: http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/83094-guide-legendary-crafting-materials-drop-locations

Comment: I agree that answer is the weak sauce. I prompted Mad Scientist to improve it with a comment but I guess I'll just do it myself at this point.

Comment: @StrixVaria I've added a hopefully improved answer compared to what existed. I didn't include the where to farm suggestion since I didn't want to copy and paste the answer from diablo fans. Hopefully that plus the edit to the question body makes it a bit better in your opinion.

Comment: @Rapida Fair enough. Voted to close my own question :P